# feature creation window issue

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, features, windows, parameters

When I click to create a feature, a window opens to define its attributes. However, with each created feature, this window does not appear in the same position and is shifted downwards. The size is also different and disproportionate. What is the issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Stupid bot, the issue is, while not utterly obviously described, clear. The question came up some while ago, I don't know whether an answer was posted. Please use the search to verify.

Comment: I know the issue with the window, which is mooving down. It is very confusing if you dont know this. But i didnt noticed a changing Size. For me the solution is just to know this issue and mooving it up before it disappears.nerverless it would be nice to fix this

Comment: I couldn't find the other topic that addressed the same question, it might have been deleted.
But yes, I manually move the window each time when it goes too far, but there must be a solution because I have worked with QGIS in the past and I'm certain I didn't have this issue.
It's quite frustrating, although it's not a major problem, but I hope to find the solution someday.

Comment: I found the topic that discusses this. The only solution for now would be to use version 3.18.3 of QGIS. It appears that there is no such issue with this version.
Perhaps this problem will be resolved in future versions of QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

this issue has been resolved with version 3.32.1 of QGIS. Have a great day!